# Next and the next

Tags: articles

I'll see you next Monday.

I'll look at it at the next meeting.

I already know both of them are correct but what if I said the second sentence the same as the first one without "the" and "at"?

In what circumstances can we use next with "the"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider *next* as an adjective only, then typically it's used without a preceding *the* when referring to days of the week, or weeks, seasons, years and so on:

> We're going camping next week.
>
> My appointment is next Wednesday.
>
> See you next year!

Otherwise, generally speaking, you would use the preceding *the*:

> I'm speaking at the next board meeting.
>
> Please bring in the next client.

Of course, these are generalisations, and there would be exceptions when speaking informally.

Comment: One exception: *I lived next door to them.*